# Netbeans 6.8 & Glassfish 2.1.1

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, executable-jar

I am using Netbeans 6.8 with Windows OS 7.

I downloaded "glassfish-installer-v2.1.1-b31g-windows" executable jar file to my harddrive.  I open this jar with Java Platform SE binary by right clicking the jar file and chosing "Open."  A folder called "glassfish" is placed in the same folder as the jar.  The glassfish server is now downloaded to my harddrive???

I open Netbeans and then chose Tools->Servers->Add Server.  The name I use is MyGlassfish2.1.1.  From the Server choices I chose GlassFish v2.x in the box above the Name and click "Next" button.

I then try to add a Server Location.  I try to place the path to the folder "glassfish" but it continues the path into the glassfish folder.  For instance I try to put in "C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish" and select the "Choose" button.  The dialogue box then goes into the glassfish folder which list the following folders:

bin
docs
imq
javadb
jbi
lib
META-INF
samples
updatecenter

I try to go into each one but doesn't seem to accept this.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm really a newbie at this Server stuff.  Totally lost now.  Help!!!

Sally

Answer (score 1):

Installing GlassFish Server 2.1.1 is a multistep process.

After reading through your description, it seems like you might have skipped step 3 and step 4 from this page: https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/v2.1.1-final.html.

You may want to 'install' the server is some place like 'C:\Sun\GlassFish, too.